# What's the benefit of .Cast over .Select?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a type with implicit conversion operators to most base types and tried to use `.Cast<string>()` on a collection of this type, which failed. As I dug into it, I noticed that casting via `as` doesn't use implicit or explicit conversion and just won't compile, so I guess that's where `.Cast` falls down. So this fails

```
var enumerable = source.Cast<string>();
```

but this works

```
var enumerable = source.Select(x => (string)x);
```

So what's the benefit of Cast? Sure, it's a couple of characters shorter, but seems a lot more limited. If it can be used for conversion, is there some benefit other than the more compact syntax?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Cast usage

The benefit of `Cast` comes when your collection only implements `IEnumerable` (ie. not the generic version). In this case, `Cast` converts all elements to `TResult` by casting, and returns `IEnumerable<TResult>`. This is handy, because all the other LINQ extension methods (including `Select`) is only declared for `IEnumerable<T>`. In code, it looks like this:

```
IEnumerable source = // getting IEnumerable from somewhere

// Compile error, because Select is not defined for IEnumerable.
var results = source.Select(x => ((string)x).ToLower());

// This works, because Cast returns IEnumerable<string>
var results = source.Cast<string>().Select(x => x.ToLower());
```

`Cast` and `OfType` are the only two LINQ extension methods that are defined for `IEnumerable`. `OfType` works like `Cast`, but skips elements that are not of type `TResult` instead of throwing an exception.

### Cast and implicit conversions

The reason why your *implicit conversion operator* is not working when you use `Cast` is simple: `Cast` casts `object` to `TResult` - and your conversion is not defined for `object`, only for your specific type. The implementation for `Cast` is something like this:

```
foreach (object obj in source)
    yield return (TResult) obj;
```

This "failure" of cast to do the conversion corresponds to the basic conversion rules - as seen by this example:

```
YourType x = new YourType(); // assume YourType defines an implicit conversion to string
object   o = x;

string bar = (string)x;      // Works, the implicit operator is hit.
string foo = (string)o;      // Fails, no implicit conversion between object and string
```

Comment: What is the query syntax version of `source.Cast<string>().Select(..)`?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Necroing the thread but there's no query syntax equivalent.  However you can use it inside a query syntax expression.  Assuming `myEnumerable` is `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerabl<T>` you can use `from x in myEnumerable.Cast<Dog>() select x`

Answer (score 6):

I checked the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) for `Cast<TResult>`, and it is an extension method to types that implement (the non-generic) `IEnumerable` interface.

It can convert a collection class (such as `ArrayList`) which doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` to one that does, allowing the richer operations (such as `Select<T>`) to be performed against it.

Answer (score 2):

Also `Cast` is much faster. I wrote a benchmark for `(string)` casting:

```
object[] arr = new[] { "123", "123", "123" ... }; //total 30 elements
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Select | 21.182 ns | 1.8182 ns | 0.0997 ns | 0.0076 | 48 B |
| Cast | 3.791 ns | 0.4695 ns | 0.0257 ns | - | - |

Not bad, 7X faster.

Another benchmark that casts an `int` array to `enum` which should probably take more resources?

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Select | 17.637 ns | 3.765 ns | 0.2064 ns | 0.0076 |
| Cast | 9.229 ns | 7.030 ns | 0.3853 ns | 0.0089 |

Still 2x faster.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question asks "What's the benefit of .Cast over .Select?" - it's speed.