# Why does using Linq's .Select() return IEnumerable<dynamic> even though the type is clearly defined?

Tags: linq, dynamic, casting, dapper

I'm using Dapper to return dynamic objects and sometimes mapping them manually.  Everything's working fine, but I was wondering what the laws of casting were and why the following examples hold true.

(for these examples I used 'StringBuilder' as my known type, though it is usually something like 'Product')

Example1: Why does this return an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` even though 'makeStringBuilder' clearly returns a `StringBuilder` object?

Example2: Why does this build, but 'Example1' wouldn't if it was `IEnumerable<StringBuilder>`?

Example3: Same question as Example2?

```
private void test()
    {
        List<dynamic> dynamicObjects = {Some list of dynamic objects};

        IEnumerable<dynamic> example1 = dynamicObjects.Select(s => makeStringBuilder(s));

        IEnumerable<StringBuilder> example2 = dynamicObjects.Select(s => (StringBuilder)makeStringBuilder(s));

        IEnumerable<StringBuilder> example3 = dynamicObjects.Select(s => makeStringBuilder(s)).Cast<StringBuilder>();

    }

    private StringBuilder makeStringBuilder(dynamic s)
    {
        return new StringBuilder(s);
    }
```

With the above examples, is there a recommended way of handling this? and does casting like this hurt performance?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry...example 1 builds in its current form, but wouldn't if it looked like : IEnumerable<StringBuilder>.  I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `dynamic`, even as a parameter, the entire expression is handled via dynamic binding and will result in being "dynamic" at compile time (since it's based on its run-time type).  This is covered in 7.2.2 of the C# spec:

> However, if an expression is a dynamic expression (i.e. has the type dynamic) this indicates that any binding that it participates in should be based on its run-time type (i.e. the actual type of the object it denotes at run-time) rather than the type it has at compile-time. The binding of such an operation is therefore deferred until the time where the operation is to be executed during the running of the program. This is referred to as dynamic binding.

In your case, using the cast will safely convert this to an `IEnumerable<StringBuilder>`, and should have very little impact on performance.  The `example2` version is very slightly more efficient than the `example3` version, but both have very little overhead when used in this way.

Comment: there's also a semantic difference between the last two examples example2 will use either cast or custom conversion if one exist whereas example3 will only use casts

Comment: @RuneFS `Enumerable.Cast<T>` actually uses a standard cast to `T` in its iterator.  The main difference is just some short circuiting (it'll check to see if it is actually an `IEnumerable<T>` up front, etc), and that it runs through its own iterator.  Explicit conversions will still work in the second case.

Comment: MSDN says otherwise "If an element cannot be cast to type TResult, this method will throw an exception."

Comment: @RuneFS Yes - if it can't be cast.  The same thing will happen with `example2` above...

Comment: Nope example2 can either be cast or converted. example3 is _only_ a cast. The cast and oftype works similarly oftype returns those of a given type ie those that can be cast to that type (not converted) whereas cast() will fail where oftype ignores the element

Comment: @RuneFS Try it.  Implicit and explicit conversions work with `Enumerable.Cast<T>` - internally, it just does (effecitively): `foreach (var item in enumeration) yield return (T)item;`

Comment: Was this change introduced in the latest version of the BCL?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132500/whats-the-benefit-of-cast-over-select for an example)

Answer (score 1):

While I can't speak very well to the "why", I think you should be able to write example1 as:

```
IEnumerable<StringBuilder> example1 = dynamicObjects.Select<dynamic, StringBuilder>(s => makeStringBuilder(s));
```

You need to tell the compiler what type the projection should take, though I'm sure someone else can clarify why it can't infer the correct type.  But I believe by specifying the projection type, you can avoid having to actually cast, which should yield some performance benefit.

Comment: Fascinating.  I've never seen Select<TIn,TOut> before.  I suppose it's simply because the compiler can't infer the delegate signature (not sure if that's how it's stated) when using dynamic type.  Because there isn't any casting whatsoever here, I would assume this performs the best and is the right way of doing it.  

Copsey answered the question, so I gave him the answer, but this was extremely useful and was what I was looking for.