# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.UInt64'

Tags: c#

Is `byte` convertible to `ulong`?

It would seem so. This doesn't throw:

```
byte wtf = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.GetAddressBytes()[0];
ulong ffs = (ulong)wtf;
```

OK so let's try to convert the whole array in one:

```
ulong[] ip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.GetAddressBytes().Cast<ulong>().ToArray();
```

This throws!?

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.UInt64'.'

Eh? Mr. Interpreter, how is it possible you were able to cast `System.Byte` to `System.UInt64` when I asked you to do this for variable `wtf`, but when I'm asking you to do this for the whole array at once you complain?

In all honesty, what's going on here? Am I sleepy already and missing something simple? Could someone kindly explain this to me?

Comment: You want to use `.Select(x => (ulong)x)` instead. `Cast<T>` is used for another reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132500/whats-the-benefit-of-cast-over-select

Comment: Just for sake of completeness, you could also do `ulong[] ulongArray = Array.ConvertAll(byteArray, v => (ulong) v);`. There should be no practical difference to doing `ulong[] ulongArray = byteArray.Select(v => (ulong) v).ToArray();` considering the small array sizes here involved. Choosing one over the other would come down to which of the two you would deem to be more readable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for `Enumerable.Cast<T>` states the following:

> The source sequence for this method is IEnumerable, which means the
>   elements have the compile-time static type of object. The only type
>   conversions that are performed by this method are reference
>   conversions and unboxing conversions. The runtime type of the elements
>   in the collection must match the target type, or in the case of value
>   types, the runtime type of elements must be the result of a boxing
>   conversion of the target type. **Other conversion types, such as those
>   between different numeric types, are not allowed**

So it is bascially only for casting non-generic collections to make them usable with LINQ. It only works on objects that are already of the destination type during runtime (or boxed), which isn't the case for `byte` and  `ulong`, what is rather a re-interpretation of the bytes in memory.

You have to use `Select` to perform the cast:

```
ulong[] ip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.GetAddressBytes()
              .Select(x => (ulong)x).ToArray();
```