# How to Cast a List<ownclass> to a List of<objects>

Tags: c#

I have made a my own class with its own properties, and added that to a `List<ownclass>`. For working reasons, I have to cast that to a `List<object>`. On the other hand I have to cast it back (in a later workaround).

How would this look like?

Comment: What code do you have already?

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates the procedure of casting a list of a custom class to a list of objects, casting the list of objects back into a list of the custom class and reading from the final list.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myList = new List<MyClass>()
        {
            new MyClass { MyNumber = 99 },
            new MyClass { MyNumber = 123 }
        };

        var objectList = myList.Cast<object>().ToList();
        var myConvertedList = objectList.Cast<MyClass>().ToList();

        foreach (int n in myConvertedList.Select(c => c.MyNumber))
            Console.WriteLine(n);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to cast it to a list of objects:

```
List<object> objects = ownClassList.Select( o => (object)o).ToList();
```

to cast it back :

```
List<ownclass> ownClassList = objects.Select( o=> (ownclass) o).ToList();
```

edit: you have to import system.linq

Comment: Why not use `.Cast<object>()` rather than `.Select(o => (object)o)`?

Comment: And what you're doing is converting the list, not casting it.

Comment: What I'm doing is exactly the same as .Cast on a collection (such as List<T>) which implements IEnumerable<T> , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132500/whats-the-benefit-of-cast-over-select