# List addrange different type

Tags: c#

I have 2 list of different type , one of them is float and the other is int

```
List<int> listone = new List<int>();
List<float> listtwo = new List<float>();
```

How do i use AddRange() to append all data from listtwo to listone ?

I have tried :

```
listone.AddRange((IEnumerable<int>)listtwo);
```

It returns error "InvalidCastException : Specified cast is not valid."
I also have tried creating a new `List<int>` named `temp`, filling it will data from listtwo that already converted to int , and then `listone.AddRange(temp)` , but i wonder if there is shorter/more efficient way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66544890/1245027:

In cases where you are sure that the casting is legal, you can use:

```
listone.AddRange(listtwo.Cast<int>());
```

---

In cases where there may be problems (and the types are reference types) with casting from type A to type B:

```
listone.AddRange(listtwo.Select(x => x as Type));
```

[What's the benefit of .Cast over .Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132500/whats-the-benefit-of-cast-over-select) addresses the two options.

Comment: for this specific case , although it is shorter , does Cast and the alternative answer have comparably same efficiency ?

Comment: I imagine they generate very similar IL.

Comment: Then it means , i'm sorry godot , this answer solution is shorter than the solution in your answer and i will accept this one since in the question i requested for shorter way .

Comment: Sharplab suggests that Cast generates simpler IL (though that doesn't necessarily mean more efficient): https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgCwG4CwAoeTkB0AMmAHYCOW2AkLbTjAMxIBM+A7DgN47UwstePGtRIBnYAB4ywAHwIIYCQHtSAUwQBeBOoDuCcVJmyAFAEoqtQ5IBmEZQEM5CpcGC7lWnWv3W7juXNLakUVdQIAQQATKIAlB1IAczUTULcPAgBlNQg1AGNgEzAteSLSYDMwMwteAF8cWqA https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgCwG4CwAoeTkB0AMmAHYCOW2AkLbTjAMxIBM+A7DgN47UwstePGtRIBnYAB4ywAHwIIYCQHtSAUwQBeBOoDuCcVJmyAFAEoqtQ5IBmEZQEM5CpcGC7lWnWv3W7juXNLakUVdQIAQQATKIAlB1IAczUTULcPAgBhBwlpUkCzC14AXxxioA=

Comment: No problem, I agree with you ;)

Comment: This approach is more likely to fail than the [cast to `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66544890/284240). If the type is `float` and not `int` you get an `InvalidCastException`, whereas the `(int) fl` works. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760804/why-enumerable-cast-raises-an-invalidcastexception

Comment: To be safe, if there's uncertainty about the casting, you should do `.Select(x => x as Type)`

Comment: @Scroog1: no, that works only with reference types not with value types like `int`

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for pointing these out. I've learnt some new things about casting in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Select from [System.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0) to cast all elements of `float` list to `int`:

```
listone.AddRange(listtwo.Select(x=>(int) x))
```

Comment: This is the better answer since the cast supports more than `Enumerable.Cast`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760804/why-enumerable-cast-raises-an-invalidcastexception